# SQL Server 2014, select date and time in a specific time zone

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Sorry, couldn't find what I was looking for when searching related questions.

I have a SQL Server 2014 that uses UTC as the time zone as well as the SQL Server database stores in UTC.

```
select LoginDate 
from logins 
where id = 237
```

Returns>>

```
LoginDate
------------------------
2009-09-11 02:52:17.017

select TODATETIMEOFFSET(LoginDate,'-07:00') as LoginDate 
from Logins 
where id = 237
```

Returns>>

```
LoginDate
-------------------------------
2009-09-11 02:52:17.017 -07:00
```

Ultimately what I want to display is just the date in format:

```
09-10-2009
```

If I keep the offset zero it still doesn't return the date correctly:

```
select SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(LoginDate,'-07:00'), 0) 
from Logins 
where id = 237
```

Returns>>

```
2009-09-11 09:52:17.017 +00:00
```

Any help is appreciated -

Boyd

Comment: Pick up desired format from [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/), hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I think that will help once we figure out how to select the date in Central time.  in UTC the date can be 9/11/2009, but in Central time the date may be 09/10/2009, depending on the time it was entered.